# Iterating List in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I would like to iterate a list in Prolog an write a generated result into a new list.
With the predicate `next_level_segments(List of Start-, Endcoordinates)` 
I would like to calculate four lists of four coordinates between each pair of Start-, and Endcoordinates and store this four lists in Ls.
This means when I call for example

```
next_level_segments([
                       [(10,0),(3.3,0)],
                       [(3.3,0),(0,-5.8)],
                       [(0,-5.8),(-3.3,0)],
                       [(-3.3,0),(-10,0)]
                     ])
```

the predicate `segments()` should calculate the four next coordinates between
the pair of Start- and Endcoordinates for example `[(10,0),(3.3,0)]`.
So next_level_segments should iterate through the list of Start and Endpoints, segments should do the calculation and the result of four list, with each four pairs of coordinates should be stored in the a resulting list.

When I call `next_level_segments()` with a list of four coordinates, the calculation is done and the coordinates are generated when i look at the trace, but aren't stored correctly.
As far as I can see it in the trace, the last list of four coordinates is missing.
Maybe somebody may have a look and have some advice what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you

```
segments([(Sx,Sy),(Ex,Ey)],Ls):-
    X2 is Sx+(Ex-Sx)/3,
    Y2 is Sy+(Ey-Sy)/3,
    R1 is sqrt((X2-Sx)*(X2-Sx)+(Y2-Ey)*(Y2-Ey)),
    Phi1 is atan((Y2-Sy)/(X2-Sx)),
    X3 is X2 +R1*cos((Phi1-240)*pi/180),
    Y3 is Y2 +R1*sin((Phi1+240)*pi/180),
    X4 is X2+(X2-Sx),
    Y4 is Y2+(Y2-Sy),
         Ls=[
             [(Sx,Sy),(X2,Y2)],
             [(X2,Y2),(X3,Y3)],
             [(X3,Y3),(X4,Y4)],
             [(X4,Y4),(Ex,Ey)]].    

next_level_segments([[(Sx,Sy),(Ex,Ey)]|E],[X|RLs]):-
    segments([(Sx,Sy),(Ex,Ey)],X),
    next_level_segments(E,RLs). 

next_level_segments([],[]).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `next_level_segments/2` needs only two clauses (instead of the three you are using). The first one should be:

```
next_level_segments([], []).
```

Both the first and the third clause you have at the moment should go because they don't do anything useful.

The recursive clause seems fine as it is at the moment.

Corrected like this, I get:

```
?- next_level_segments(
       [[(10,0),(3.3,0)],
        [(3.3,0),(0,-5.8)],
        [(0,-5.8),(-3.3,0)],
        [(-3.3,0),(-10,0)]
       ],
       X).
X = [[[(10, 0),  (7.766666666666667, 0)], [(7.766666666666667, 0),  (6.649999999999999, -1.9341234017852458)], [(6.649999999999999, -1.9341234017852458),  (5.533333333333333, 0)], [(5.533333333333333, 0),  (3.3, 0)]],
     [[(3.3, 0),  (2.2, -1.9333333333333333)], [(2.2, -1.9333333333333333),  (0.1262841490828066, -5.451200543142186)], [(0.1262841490828066, -5.451200543142186),  (1.1000000000000005, -3.8666666666666667)], [(1.1000000000000005, -3.8666666666666667),  (0, -5.8)]],
     [[(0, -5.8),  (-1.0999999999999999, -3.8666666666666663)], [(-1.0999999999999999, -3.8666666666666663),  (-3.0456930398351094, -7.310619872034865)], [(-3.0456930398351094, -7.310619872034865),  (-2.1999999999999997, -1.9333333333333327)], [(-2.1999999999999997, -1.9333333333333327),  (-3.3, 0)]],
     [[(-3.3, 0),  (-5.533333333333333, 0)], [(-5.533333333333333, 0),  (-6.65, -1.9341234017852458)], [(-6.65, -1.9341234017852458),  (-7.766666666666667, 0)], [(-7.766666666666667, 0),  (-10, 0)]]
    ].
```

Keep in mind that a *trivial* list iteration like this can also be written simply as:

```
maplist(segments, Input, Output)
```

In other words, apply `segments/2` to each corresponding element in the two lists. You would have to redefine your `segments/3` however to have two arguments instead of three, for example by re-writing the head to:

```
segments([(Sx,Sy),(Ex,Ey)], Ls)
```

(put the two first arguments in a list, as they are in your input list)

A small comment: a pair in Prolog is usually written as `X-Y`, not as `(X, Y)`. Many standard library predicates represent "pairs" as `X-Y`, for example `keysort/2`, library(pairs) and so on. If you want to, you could also give your pair a descriptive name like `pair(X,Y)` or `coordinates(X,Y)`. It doesn't really matter of only two elements, but a "tuple" with three elements like this: `(X,Y,Z)` is actually a nested term:

```
?- write_canonical((X,Y,Z)).
','(_,','(_,_))
true.
```

You get the same problem with `X-Y-Z`:

```
?- write_canonical(X-Y-Z).
-(-(_,_),_)
true.
```

At that point you could again use a term with a descriptive name, for example `triple(X, Y, Z)` or `coordinates(X, Y, Z)`.

Comment: Dear Boris! Thank you very much for your answer. I edited my implementation according to the things you wrote. If I understood you right,  I should change segment/3 to segments/2 by inserting brackets. I removed the unnecessary clauses and inserted as a third clause `next_level_segments([],[])`. I can use mapping instead of the way I did it, but I don't need to - did I understand this right?  I've done it that way, but when I call `next_level_segments([[(),()],[(),()],[(),()],[(),()]],X).` with four coordinates now I get a false.Please have another look, I guess I understood something wrong?

Comment: @claire It works fine for me, with the exact code as you showed in your edited question. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you Boris for your time!! I didn't realise that not all the coordinates have been shown in my editor, but when I copied them in a  word-document, I could see all coordinates. I send you a big hug, once again, thank you much!!!